# How to call session bean from jsp

Tags: ejb

I'm new to ejb. Actually I've created one ejb and I added reference to a web application which will call the session bean simply. How to call the session bean from the jsp file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could also prefer you to use the MVC model for your application. In that case there is no need to call a session bean from the jsp, you can call it from the servlets itself.

Check out this link to call a EJB from a servlet.
[Click](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish)

Comment: It's all very well to say that MVC is the prefered approach but there are a couple of other things to consider: Firstly, a JSP page is converted to a servlet by the container, anyway. So there is nothing conceptually wrong with accessing an EJB in a JSP. Secondly, sometimes you need information from an EJB in order to set up the page. I have that situation. I need a list of values from an EJB to set up a drop down list. So thanks for including the  correct syntax in your other answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to do that on Wildfly, but without success using @EJB annotation, probabily JSP don't have CDI. So I've implemented it on another way (not so bright):

Before the :

```
<%
    LoginAction loginAction;

    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        Context ctx=new InitialContext(properties);
        loginAction = (LoginAction) ctx.lookup("java:module/LoginAction");

        session.setAttribute("loginAction", loginAction); //this is to be able to use loginAction on EL Expressions!
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

And all the rest stays the same!

Answer (score 0):

1) the first way will be to create a direct object

use import tag to import ur class

```
< % @ page import = packageName.Classname %>
    <%
    @EJB
    Classname object = new Classname();
    %>
```

and then access methods using normal jsp

```
<%=object.callmethod()%>
```

2) the other way will be to use standard actions

```
<jsp:useBean id="beanId' class="packagename.ClassName" />
<jsp:getStudentInfo name="beanId" property="name"/>
```

Comment: I'm using default package. So, how can I mention the package. Moreover when I tried with this two way, I'm getting the error as "Unable to compile class for JSP". I'm using netbeans...

Comment: @nila
there is no need to use the page import option in case u r using the same package.
other things should work fine.

Comment: On the first step if injecting the ejb with `@EJB` and instantiate with new Classname(). This makes no sense because you're injecting and instantiating at the same time. You should remove `@EJB` because it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using EJB at service layer and in MVC , I will never advice to call a session bean from your view or jsp.you can call the session beans method by injection EJB reference using @EJB annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple..Override Jsp's jspInit method and create InitialContext object.. InitialContext object can access all the resources that have JNDI name assigned..

```
<%!

BeanIntefaceName instanceName;

%>   

<%
public void jspInit()
{
    instanceName = (BeanIntefaceName)new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/[application_name]/[module_name]/[enterprise_bean_name]/[inteface_name]");
}

instanceName.yourMethodName();
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix and match to support multiple application servers in the best way. 
The code below uses the @EJB injection for WebSphere Liberty and the InitialContext for JBoss Wildfly

```
<%!

@EJB
GitlabHelper gitAPI;

public void jspInit() {

    if (gitAPI == null) {

    try {
        gitAPI = (GitlabHelper) new InitialContext().lookup("java:module/GitlabHelper");
        System.out.println("<!-- initContext has been used -->");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

%>
```